# Use references to UIManager script or direct for children OBJs

Tags: unity, gui

So I've got a canvas with UIManager script attached to it, the canvas has a lot of buttons and texts as children OBJs and they somehow need to communicate to each other. Should this be done through the UIManager or through direct scripts?

EDIT: Fixed, the point was to set other buttons and other UI elements active or de-active, I ended up using different methods in the UImanager script to do so, without having like 20 scripts.

Comment: Surely this is a design consideration?  What is the manager doing? what kinda of communication is needed?

Comment: You can do this any way that makes sense to you. How have you tried doing it so far? Have you run into any particular problem or area of dissatisfaction with that method? Try asking about that specific issue and we can help you find ways to solve/improve it.

Comment: If you've solved your problem, please post your solution as an Answer. Our system doesn't recognize "Fixed" as a resolution to the question.